# FFmpeg scaling with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, scaling

I'm trying to scale a video (height and width) by 1.8, but after running the above code, nothing changes to the video. Not sure what is the issue here.

```
import subprocess
import ffmpeg

def crop(input_file, output_file, x, y):
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-filter:v', 'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])

crop('/Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil1.mp4', '/Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil2.mp4', 1.8, 1.8)
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the result of `'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y)` to look like? What result do you actually get when you test that in isolation? According to the documentation, what should it look like?

Comment: ffmpeg should see `scale=1.8*iw:1.8*ih`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can not scale with 1.8, 1.8 I guess,
Try to pass valid resolution like 640, 480

For example -

```
import subprocess
import ffmpeg

def crop(input_file, output_file, x, y):
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-filter:v', 'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])

crop('/Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil1.mp4', '/Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil2.mp4', 640, 480)
```

Comment: I don't think it does anything even when I input valid resolution

Comment: can you execute this on the command line

Comment: If your getting result on command line, we can debug python part

Comment: If the command line itself is not providing results, then you have an issue in FFMPEG installation

Comment: ```ffmpeg -i /Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil1.mp4 -vf scale=640:480 /Users/Aaron/Desktop/reil2.mp4```